# How does windows copy files between network locations?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, file-io

Lets say I open up windows explorer and drag a file from a network shared folder \S1 to another network share \S2.

Do the bytes of the file stream through the computer I'm currently using?

I'm writing a simple C# program to copy these files between the storage locations. If was to use a function such as File.CopyTo, would that be equivalent to the drag/drop in explorer?

If I write the copy function myself and do it using streams, the bytes would be going through wherever the program runs, but I would be able to track the progress easier.

Comment: `Do the bytes of the file stream through the computer I'm currently using?` - Well ... yes. Can you be more specific about whats confusing you? Its a bit hard to understand what your question is asking for. Are you simply asking about progress indicators for a custom file copy? Or you actually want a detailed breakdown of how Windows talks to your NIC?

Comment: Well, one possibility is that the file never touches the computer and the transfer is handled at a lower level after being initiated by the OS.

Comment: @user3916403 yes, the bytes are routed through the copying machine. If you want to see this for yourself, you can get a program like Wireshark and watch the network traffic when you copy networked files.

Comment: I guess my concern is that windows may have efficient method for this kind of transfer which I may or may not lose out on by rolling my own custom method. why not put an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do the bytes of the file stream through the computer I'm currently using?

Yes.

> would that be equivalent to the drag/drop in explorer?

Almost, but not entirely. Bytes will still flow through the local computer, however the network traffic will be slightly different. E.g. explorer accesses thumbs.db when a folder is opened (File.CopyTo doesn't), explorer may use slightly different NetBIOS calls, different threading strategy, different buffering strategy, etc.

Comment: For completeness, note this is not *always* true.  In a SAN environment, Windows 2012 R2 allows a client to copy files from one server to another without the data ever leaving the SAN.  (The SAN has to support this feature, obviously, and I think the client has to be running Windows 8.1 as well.  I'm afraid I don't recall offhand what Microsoft call it so can't provide a reference.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston It's called [Offloaded Data Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm not sure it was a good idea to bring it up, because ODX is a very niche feature that does not apply to the general case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be via the laptop.

I am currently working away from the office and connected to a public wifi.

In the task manager when i initiate the copy from one network location to the other my wireless connection chart jumps from 0%-1% to a consistent 10-15%.

After each files has transfered it drops to 0% and then starts the next one.
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNAK8.png)